# C++ LNK Error 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

rmap_utils.h

```
#ifndef UTILS_RANGE_MAP_H
#define UTILS_RANGE_MAP_H


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"


class rmap_utils
{
public:
        rmap_utils::rmap_utils(){}
        rmap_utils::~rmap_utils(){}

int loadRmap(const std::string &path, float *& xMap, float *& yMap, float *& zMap, unsigned char *&rgbMap, int &height, int &width);

cv::Mat visualize_depth_image(float *img, int width, int height, bool visualize, std::string wName = "rangeMap");
cv::Mat visualize_rgb_image(unsigned char *img, int width, int height, bool visualize, std::string wName = "rangeMap");
cv::Mat visualize_normalized_rgb_image(float *img, int width, int height, bool visualize, std::string wName = "rangeMap");

float compute_rangeMap_resolution(float *xMap, float *yMap, float *zMap, int width, int height);


};
#endif
```

rmap_utils.cpp

```
#include "rmap_utils.h"

void Tokenize(const std::string &line, std::vector<std::string> &tokens, const std::string &delimiters = " ", const bool skipEmptyCells = true, const int maxNumTokens = std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
{
    tokens.clear();

    int nTokens = 0;
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    std::string::size_type lastPos = 0;

    if(skipEmptyCells)
    {
        // Skip delimiters at beginning.
        lastPos = line.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
        // Find first "non-delimiter".
        pos  = line.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

        while ( (std::string::npos != pos || std::string::npos != lastPos) && (nTokens < maxNumTokens) )
        {
            // Found a token, add it to the vector.
            tokens.push_back(line.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
            nTokens++;
            // Skip delimiters
            lastPos = line.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
            // Find next "non-delimiter"
            pos = line.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while ( (std::string::npos != pos)  && (nTokens < maxNumTokens) )
        {
            pos = line.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
            tokens.push_back(line.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
            nTokens++;
            lastPos = pos+1;
        }   
    }

}

template <typename T> void Read_Array(std::ifstream &filev, T* &aData, unsigned long int &nData, const bool binaryFile = true)
{
    if (!filev.is_open() )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR (Read_Array): file is not open";
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(binaryFile)
    {
        //read number of elements
        filev.read((char*)&nData, sizeof(nData) );
        aData = new T[nData];
        //read data
        filev.read((char*)aData, sizeof(T)*nData );

        if(filev.gcount() != (sizeof(T)*nData) )
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR (Read_Array): filev.gcount() != (sizeof(T)*nData)  " << filev.gcount() << " " << (sizeof(T)*nData) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Are you sure you opened the file in binary mode?";
            getchar();
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(!filev.good())
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR (Read_Array): !filev.good() [eof fail bad] [" << filev.eof() << " " << filev.fail() << " " << filev.bad() << "]" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Are you sure you opened the file in binary mode?";
            getchar();
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //read number of elements
        std::string line;
        std::getline(filev, line);
        filev >> nData;
        aData = new T[nData];
        //read data
        T* ptrData = aData;
        for(unsigned long int da=0; da<nData; da++)
        {
            filev >> *ptrData;
            ptrData++;
        }
        std::getline(filev, line);

        if(!filev.good())
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR (Read_Array): !filev.good() [eof fail bad] [" << filev.eof() << " " << filev.fail() << " " << filev.bad() << "]" << std::endl;
            getchar();
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}

template <typename T> void Read_Vector(std::ifstream &filev, std::vector<T> &vData, const bool binaryFile = true)
{
    if (!filev.is_open() )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR (Read_Vector): file is not open";
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }

    unsigned long int nData = 0;
    if(binaryFile)
    {
        //read number of elements
        filev.read((char*)&nData, sizeof(nData) );
        vData.resize((size_t)nData);
        //read data
        filev.read((char*)(&vData[0]), sizeof(T)*nData );
        if(filev.gcount() != (sizeof(T)*nData) )
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR (Read_Vector): filev.gcount() != (sizeof(T)*nData)  " << filev.gcount() << " " << (sizeof(T)*nData) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Are you sure you opened the file in binary mode?";
            getchar();
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(!filev.good())
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR (Read_Vector): !filev.good() [eof fail bad] [" << filev.eof() << " " << filev.fail() << " " << filev.bad() << "]" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Are you sure you opened the file in binary mode?";
            getchar();
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //read number of elements
        std::string line;
        std::getline(filev, line);
        filev >> nData;
        vData.resize((size_t)nData);
        //read data
        T* ptrData = &vData[0];
        for(unsigned long int da=0; da<nData; da++)
        {
            filev >> (*ptrData);
            ptrData++;
        }
        std::getline(filev, line);

        if(!filev.good())
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR (Read_Vector): !filev.good() [eof fail bad] [" << filev.eof() << " " << filev.fail() << " " << filev.bad() << "]" << std::endl;
            getchar();
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T> T LexicalCast(const std::string& s)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);

    T result;
    if ((ss >> result).fail() || !(ss >> std::ws).eof())
    {
        //throw std::bad_cast();
        std::cout << "ERROR:Impossible to cast " << s;
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }

    return result;
}

//passi i puntatori vuoti e lui elaborando li riempe per come ti servono
int loadRmap(const std::string &path, float *& xMap, float *& yMap, float *& zMap, unsigned char *&rgbMap, int &height, int &width)
{
    bool binaryFile = true;

    std::ifstream in(path.c_str(), std::ios::binary|std::ios::in);
    if(!in.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR (RangeMap::Load_RMap): Problems opening file";
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }


    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    int nValidPoints = 0;
    bool texture = false;
    int nChannels = 1;
    double resolution;

    //read header
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        getline (in, line);
        // Ignore empty lines
        if (line == "")
            continue;

        // Tokenize the line
        Tokenize(line, tokens, "\t\r " );

        // first line
        if (tokens[0] == "RMap")
            continue;

        // version
        if (tokens[0] == "version")
        {
            continue;
        }

        // height
        if (tokens[0] == "height")
        {
            height = LexicalCast<int>(tokens[1]);
            continue;
        }

        // width
        if (tokens[0] == "width")
        {
            width = LexicalCast<int>(tokens[1]);
            continue;
        }

        // nValidPoints
        if (tokens[0] == "nValidPoints")
        {
            nValidPoints = LexicalCast<int>(tokens[1]);
            continue;
        }

        // resolution
        if (tokens[0] == "resolution")
        {
            resolution = LexicalCast<double>(tokens[1]);
            continue;
        }

        // texture
        if (tokens[0] == "texture")
        {
            texture = true;
            if (tokens[1] == "GrayScale")
            {
                nChannels = 1;
            }
            else if (tokens[1] == "BGR")
            {
                nChannels = 3;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "ERROR (RangeMap::Load_RMap): tokens[1] != \"GrayScale\" and tokens[1] != \"BGR\" ";
                getchar();
                exit(-1);
            }
            continue;
        }

        // end_header
        if (tokens[0] == "headerEnd")
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if(in.eof())
    {
        in.close();
        std::cout << "ERROR (RangeMap::Load_RMap): end_header tag not reached";
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }

    //read valid point map
    bool* validMap = NULL;
    unsigned long int nTotalPoints = 0;
    Read_Array(in, validMap, nTotalPoints, binaryFile);
    if(nTotalPoints != width*height)
    {
        in.close();
        std::cout << "ERROR (RangeMap::Load_RMap): nTotalPoints != m_width*m_height  " << nTotalPoints << " != " << width << " * " << height << std::endl;
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }

    //read maps
    std::vector<float> xVals;
    std::vector<float> yVals;
    std::vector<float> zVals;
    Read_Vector(in, xVals, binaryFile);
    Read_Vector(in, yVals, binaryFile);
    Read_Vector(in, zVals, binaryFile);
    if(xVals.size() != nValidPoints)
    {
        in.close();
        std::cout << "ERROR (RangeMap::Load_RMap): vMap_X.size() != nValidPoints  " << xVals.size() << " != " << nValidPoints << std::endl;
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(yVals.size() != nValidPoints)
    {
        in.close();
        std::cout << "ERROR (RangeMap::Load_RMap): vMap_Y.size() != nValidPoints  " << yVals.size() << " != " << nValidPoints << std::endl;
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(zVals.size() != nValidPoints)
    {
        in.close();
        std::cout << "ERROR (RangeMap::Load_RMap): vMap_Z.size() != nValidPoints  " << zVals.size() << " != " << nValidPoints << std::endl;
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }

    //if(xMap)
    //{
    //  delete[] xMap;
    //}
    xMap = new float[width*height];
    /*if(yVals)
    {
        delete[] yVals;
    }*/
    yMap = new float[width*height];
    /*if(zVals)
    {
        delete[] zVals;
    }*/
    zMap = new float[width*height];

    float* ptrvMap_X = &xVals[0];
    float* ptrvMap_Y = &yVals[0];
    float* ptrvMap_Z = &zVals[0];
    bool* ptrValidMap = validMap;
    float* ptrXmap = xMap;
    float* ptrYmap = yMap;
    float* ptrZmap = zMap;
    for(unsigned long int po=0; po<nTotalPoints; po++)
    {
        if(*ptrValidMap)
        {
            *ptrXmap = *(ptrvMap_X++);
            *ptrYmap = *(ptrvMap_Y++);
            *ptrZmap = *(ptrvMap_Z++);
        }
        else
        {
            *ptrZmap = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
        }
        ptrXmap++;
        ptrYmap++;
        ptrZmap++;
        ptrValidMap++;
    }

    delete[] validMap;

    //read texture
    if(texture)
    {
        IplImage* m_texture = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), 8, nChannels);

        rgbMap = new unsigned char[width*height*3];

        in.read( (char*)(m_texture->imageData), height*m_texture->widthStep );

        if(in.gcount() != height*m_texture->widthStep)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR (RangeMap::Load_RMap): in.gcount() != m_height*m_texture->widthStep  " << in.gcount() << " " << height*m_texture->widthStep;
            getchar();
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(!in.good())
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR (RangeMap::Load_RMap): !in.good() in reading m_texture [eof fail bad] [" << in.eof() << " " << in.fail() << " " << in.bad() << "]";
            getchar();
            exit(-1);
        }

        for (int j=0; j<height; j++)
        {
            for ( int i=0; i<width; i++)
            {
                if ( nChannels == 3)
                {
                    rgbMap[ j*width*3+i*3 ] = ((unsigned char *)(m_texture->imageData))[ j * m_texture->widthStep + i*3];
                    rgbMap[ j*width*3+i*3 +1 ] = ((unsigned char *)(m_texture->imageData))[ j * m_texture->widthStep + i*3 +1];
                    rgbMap[ j*width*3+i*3 +2 ] = ((unsigned char *)(m_texture->imageData))[ j * m_texture->widthStep + i*3 +2];
                }
                else
                {
                    rgbMap[ j*width*3+i*3+2 ] = ((unsigned char *)(m_texture->imageData))[ j * m_texture->widthStep + i];
                    rgbMap[ j*width*3+i*3+1 ] = ((unsigned char *)(m_texture->imageData))[ j * m_texture->widthStep + i];
                    rgbMap[ j*width*3+i*3 ] = ((unsigned char *)(m_texture->imageData))[ j * m_texture->widthStep + i];
                }
            }
        }

        /*cvNamedWindow("cicciux", 0);
        cvShowImage("cicciux", m_texture);
        cvWaitKey(0);*/

        cvReleaseImage(&m_texture);
    }
    else
    {
        rgbMap = NULL;
    }

    in.close();

    return nValidPoints;
}

cv::Mat visualize_depth_image(float *img, int width, int height, bool visualize, std::string wName)
{

    cv::Mat mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);

    float dmax = -1;
    float dmin = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();

    for ( int j=0; j<height; j++)
    {
        for ( int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
            if ( img[j*width+i] == img[j*width+i] )
            {
                if ( img[j*width+i] > dmax )
                    dmax = img[j*width+i];

                if (img[j*width+i]<dmin)
                    dmin = img[j*width+i];
            }
        }
    }

    for ( int j=0; j<height; j++)
    {
        for ( int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
            if (  img[j*width+i] ==  img[j*width+i] )
            {
                unsigned char pixel = cv::saturate_cast<unsigned char>( ((img[j*width+i] - dmin)* 255.0f) / (dmax-dmin) ) ;

                mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0] = pixel;
                mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1] = pixel;
                mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2] = pixel;
            }
            else
            {
                mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0] = 0;
                mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1] = 0;
                mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2] = 255;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( visualize) 
    {   
        cv::imshow(wName, mat);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }

    return mat;
}

cv::Mat visualize_rgb_image(unsigned char *img, int width, int height, bool visualize, std::string wName)
{

    cv::Mat mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);

    for ( int j=0; j<height; j++)
    {
        for ( int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
            for ( int c=0; c<3; c++)
            {
                mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[c] = img[j*width*3 + i*3 + c];
            }
        }
    }

    if ( visualize ) 
    {   
        cv::imshow(wName, mat);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }

    return mat;
}

cv::Mat visualize_normalized_rgb_image(float *img, int width, int height, bool visualize, std::string wName)
{

    cv::Mat mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);

    for ( int j=0; j<height; j++)
    {
        for ( int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
            for ( int c=0; c<3; c++)
            {
                mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[c] = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::floor(img[j*width*3 + i*3 + c] * 255));
            }
        }
    }

    if ( visualize) 
    {   
        cv::imshow(wName, mat);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }

    return mat;
}

float compute_rangeMap_resolution(float *xMap, float *yMap, float *zMap, int width, int height)
{
    float res = 0.0f;
    int nCount = 0;

    for ( int j=0; j<height-1; j++)
    {
        for ( int i=0; i<width-1; i++)
        {
            if ( zMap[j*width+i] == zMap[j*width+i] )
            {
                if ( zMap[j*width+i+1] == zMap[j*width+i+1] )
                {
                    nCount ++ ;
                    res += (zMap[j*width+i]-zMap[j*width+i+1])*(zMap[j*width+i]-zMap[j*width+i+1]) + (yMap[j*width+i]-yMap[j*width+i+1])*(yMap[j*width+i]-yMap[j*width+i+1]) + (xMap[j*width+i]-xMap[j*width+i+1])*(xMap[j*width+i]-xMap[j*width+i+1]);
                }
                if ( zMap[(j+1)*width+i] == zMap[(j+1)*width+i] )
                {
                    nCount ++ ;
                    res += (zMap[j*width+i]-zMap[(j+1)*width+i])*(zMap[j*width+i]-zMap[(j+1)*width+i]) + (yMap[j*width+i]-yMap[(j+1)*width+i])*(yMap[j*width+i]-yMap[(j+1)*width+i]) + (xMap[j*width+i]-xMap[(j+1)*width+i])*(xMap[j*width+i]-xMap[(j+1)*width+i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    res /= nCount;
    res = sqrt(res);
    return res;
}
```

Error List:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl rmap_utils::loadRmap(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,float * &,float * &,float * &,unsigned char * &,int &,int &)" (?loadRmap@rmap_utils@@QEAAHAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEAPEAM11AEAPEAEAEAH3@Z) referenced in function main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `rmap_utils.cpp` replace

`int loadRmap(const std::string &path, float *& xMap, float *& yMap, float *& zMap, unsigned char *&rgbMap, int &height, int &width)`

With:

`int rmap_utils::loadRmap(const std::string &path, float *& xMap, float *& yMap, float *& zMap, unsigned char *&rgbMap, int &height, int &width)`